# why this shell script could not work?

Tags: regex, bash, shell

My script like this:

```
#!/bin/env bash

monitor_sock_raw1=socket,id=hmqmondev,port=55919,host=127.0.0.1,nodelay,server,nowait

msock=${monitor_sock_raw1##,port=}
msock=${msock%%,host=}

echo $msock
```

I expect get '55919', but the result is:

```
socket,id=hmqmondev,port=55919,host=127.0.0.1,nodelay,server,nowait
```

Why and how to fix this bug?

Comment: Using awk `awk -F'[=,]' '{print $5}' <<< $monitor_sock_raw1`

Answer (score 3):

For a simple requirement like this, `bash` supports a `regex` (See [`bash` ERE support](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression#regular_expression_matching)) approach using the `~` operator which you can use it to match the `port` string and *match* the digits after it.

```
#!/bin/env bash

var='monitor_sock_raw1=socket,id=hmqmondev,port=55919,host=127.0.0.1,nodelay'

if [[ $var =~ ^.*port=([[:digit:]]+).*$ ]]; then 
    printf "%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fi
```

The captured group from the regex is stored in the array `BASH_REMATCH` from which the first element after index `0` i.e. index `1` contains the value of 1<sup>st</sup> captured group.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dKhQHn/1)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add wildcards or the patterns wont match. The pattern needs to match the whole start or end of the text.

```
msock=${monitor_sock_raw1##*,port=}
msock=${msock%%,host=*}
```

Answer (score 0):

Script that solves your problem.

```
#!/bin/bash

monitor_sock_raw1="socket,id=hmqmondev,port=55919,host=127.0.0.1,nodelay,server,nowait"

msock=(${monitor_sock_raw1##*port=})

echo ${msock%%,*}
```